# Files not transferring correctly from local drive to server

Tags: javascript, html, css, server

My code works properly and is functional when opening it from my local files, but when I open it up from the server I get an error message: "300 multiple choices" that says the files were not found on the server, however when I access the server all files seem to be in there respective places. I am unsure if it is a problem within my code, the server, or VPN connection. How can I troubleshoot to resolve this error?

I have tried uploading it multiple times, but am unsure what I can do besides that

here is my github as I am unsure where the problem is if it exists in my code

https://github.com/fallynlogan/horoscope-quiz

Comment: 300 Multiple choices means that the browser needs more specificity in choosing certain attributes (ex Video format options, File extension options, etc...) that are not explicitly specified in the code. In the first example (of video format), the browser could be trying to prompt the user for further instructions on what video format options to use, as it is capable of using multiple options

Comment: Are you using Apache? If so, people have reported success by adding `Options -MultiViews` `CheckSpelling off`to their htacess file.

Comment: No, I'm using FileZilla. & what example are you speaking of?